# Не считываются аргументы в команде

Tags: python, discord.py

Есть вот такая команда:

```
async def countrys(ctx, names: str):
```

Вылетает с кучей ошибок. Что делать, как починить, чтобы всё, что написано в этой строке после команды, считывалось?

Вот ошибки:

```
[2023-10-04 13:45:22] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command countrys
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "x-wingide-python-shell://168682432/2", line 20, in countrys
TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 8

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "D:\Pyton\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list expected at most 1 argument, got 8
```

Comment: Пример вызова команды покажите. Что вы ожидаете получить в `names`?

Comment: Пример: >countrys Name1 Name2 Name3

Comment: попробуйте `async def countrys(ctx, *, names: str):`

Comment: или `async def countrys(ctx, *names):`, чтобы в `names` был кортеж аргументов

Comment: попробовал и то и то, ошибка таже

Comment: А как вам тогда код из ответа помог?)

Comment: я нашёл ошибку в другом месте)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то Вам должно подойти это:

```
@bot.command()
async def countrys(ctx, *args):
    print(args)
```

Если необходимо разделение через запятые/пробелы аргументов и запихнуть их в список, то такая конструкция может помочь:

```
@bot.command()
async def countrys(ctx, *args):
    print(args) 

    arguments = ' '.join(args)
    print(arguments) 

    wrote_args = [arguments][0].split(', ')    
    print(wrote_args)
```

Пример:
`!countrys Name1, Name2, Name3, Name Name`

```
('Name1,', 'Name2,', 'Name3,', 'Name', 'Name')
Name1, Name2, Name3, Name Name
['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name Name']
```